# Email clients (outlook) hiding / not rendering my images

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have a custom email template where I have an img tag that is being flagged by Outlooks security and does not render unless the recipient clicks okay, or disables the security setting. Is there a way to code an image into an email so it is not a security risk? I am using a php script that retrieves my correct image, is this the issue?

Comment: If you have a vector image, you could try copying the SVG code and including it directly in the document. For formats like JPG or PNG I guess no - its a security feature, that was designed to prohibit that. The only thing that comes to my mind is including it as an attachment, but even then they will probably not get downloaded automatically. Moreover, this makes the user experience rather worse than better, results in bigger size, etc. - not a good idea at all actually.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook clients hide images by default and require the setting to be turned off for all or for the user to specifically mark the sender as 'safe'. Gmail also does this and there may be others.

Large companies enforce this in their networks for security reasons.
The downside to this is many use their work addresses for mailing lists and personal accounts when they really shouldn't.

Don't try and circumvent this setting, it is there for a reason.